# Compile again MVC4 solution on run time

Tags: c#, compilation, runtime

I'm update some values on *.config* files and I'm reloading that sections  but is not refreshing on my *bin* folder, until I rebuild the solution I think that I can use this *CodeDomProvider.CreateCompiler*  but I don't know how to do it for mvc solution. Some advices for me please.

This is my code

```
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("configuration");
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();

using (Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider foo =new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider())
                {
                    var res = foo.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
                        new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters()
                        {
                            GenerateInMemory = true
                        }
                    );

                }
```

Comment: That will not help you.  You need to recycle the AppDomain.

Comment: You don't need to do that. Asp.net have auto detection mechanism for file changes. It serves old request with old files but when a file change is detected, It finishes old requests and recycles the app domain to load fresh files. You haven't mentioned why do want to have such custom behavior? What problem are you facing?

Comment: Well, I´m new with this and indeed after the update on my .config files when I´m running the app this are reload and I can see the changes, I´m making changes on some connections string. But I think that on deployed solution I should to refresh the files on bin folder, but I´m not sure is just something that I suppose.
I´m not really familiar with the behaviour of these files. Any advices?